# Prevent Page Break between 2 div elements

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing, page-break

I'm having quite the problem now. It's only bothering in Firefox (Testing with FF10), this bug doesn't happen in Chrome 17 or any IE.

Here's the thing. I have a page architecture looking like this

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a">
        <img src="foo/bar.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
            <!--short content-->
        </div>
        <div id="d">
            <!--long content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Some asked for the a part of the CSS. My code here being simplified a lot, here's a simplified version of the css to match.

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
}

#a{
    height: 156px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 2px;
    width: 918px;
}

#b {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 958px;
}

#c{
    background: url("images/top_content.gif") no-repeat scroll left top #FFFFFF;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#d{
    padding: 40px 0px;
}
```

as a bonus, the calculated height of the #d div is 874px (caculated with firebug)

Should aslo point out that when the content is short enough to fit in the page, the content section (#d) won't have a page break and stays on the first page.

[image]

This only happens when, for example in chrome, I can see that the content of #d will bleed out on the second page.

So here is the question. How do I prevent a line break between the #c and #d divs?

Comment: can you update your question also posting the CSS of container, a, b and c elements ? A closing `>` is missing on you container div anyway

Comment: I just added a good part of the CSS to the Question.

Comment: Is this only happening during printing, or when viewing the page normally?

Comment: Only during printing... I don't see how you could have a page break in a normal webpage... :)

Comment: Well, I just patched up the problem by putting the #a and #c divs at the beginning of the #d div and making them show up, with CSS, only when you print the page. But if someone has a reliable answer to this question, he is welcome to post it. That bypass wont work everytime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean how to prevent a page-break when printing?

```
#c{
    page-break-after: avoid;
}

#d {
    page-break-before: avoid;
}
```

Note that the 'new' way of doing it would be using the generic `break-before` and `break-after` like this:

```
#c{
    break-after: avoid-page;
}

#d {
    break-before: avoid-page;
}
```

But this is not supported in all browsers yet. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after

Comment: Well that did give me some hope. I tried it, didn't work. W3Schools says: 'Note: Firefox, Chrome, and Safari do not support the property values "avoid", "left", or "right"'. Well, at least that's good to know. Can come handy later down the line.

Comment: Hmm, that's too bad. What happens if you have some smaller subdivs within #d? Does that break #d up?

Comment: There's already a ton of subdivisions in the #d div. I just simplified the code for posting the question without revealing too much on the project. In the #d div, theres 2 other divs, one containing paragraphs and the other a slider.

Comment: In that case, I'm really out of ideas... I'm sorry :( http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/css/at-page.html might provide some interesting information regarding an @page annotation, but I'm afraid it might not solve your problem.

Comment: This has been replaced with `break-before` and `break-after` with the value `avoid-page`. Reference: [MDN | break-after - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after)

Answer (score 1):

I came here, with the same problem. And I found a solution!

**My Situation**:

- I have a div that serves as a heading
- then another div that contains a very long pre
- that pre extends across multiple pages

**Example**:

```
<div>Heading</div>
<div>
    <pre>Very long pre.</pre>
</div>
```

**The Problem**:

- My Heading Div appears on page 1
- The pre starts on page 2 - so HUGE gap between the "heading" and content.

**The Solution:**

Finally, I tried making my pre style `display: inline`. Tada! Now my heading div and the beginning of the pre start on page 1 together!

Perhaps you can mess with the display of your elements to control this better. Hope this helps whoever may stumble here again!

Answer (score 0):

I had `height: 100%;` in code and every page breaks.