# How to check the position of an element?

Tags: javascript

I have the script below. basically, it breaks the pictures with titles. The problem is that sometimes I have the title at the end of the page and the pictures on the next page.
I would like to be able to test if the title is to far in the page that it will go to the next page.
something like "if Title position > 3/4 page then page break.

Thank you.

```html
function CheckTitle(value) {
    if(Title!=value) {
        if (column == 2) {
            document.writeln('</tr>');
            column = 1;
        }
        document.writeln('<tr>');
        document.writeln('<td colspan="35" width="1000px" style="background-color: rgba(0,159,227,1);color:white;font-size: larger">' + value + '</td>');
        document.writeln('</tr>');
    }
    Title = value;
    ctr=ctr+1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alain. What do you mean by "the next page?" Are you using HTML for generating a print document?

Comment: I would advice to read a CSS tutorial before you continue with javascript. CSS contains alot of different rules to position elements, specify maximum width, where the whitespace should break, etc. This should make it way easier to layout your page as you want, instead of using JS to do layout calculations.

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230727/prevent-page-break-between-2-div-elements

Comment: Hi Chris, yes I do that. I actually build reports within our software that we use. We use SQL to get the data and HTML/CSS/Javascript for the Layout.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: My apologies, I thought you were asking not to extend below the viewport...to stop a page break, you can use CSS:

```
/* avoid page break after the div */
div.title {
    /* new property */
    break-after: avoid-page;

    /* legacy property */
    page-break-after: avoid;
}
```

Reference: [MDN | break-after - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after)

Comment: Actually, I'm trying the opposite. I want that every new title will stay together with the pictures, because now, in some cases, I get the Title at the bottom of the page and the pictures on a new page.

Comment: That's what the above does, it avoids putting a page break after the `div.title`

Comment: I've tried that and it's not working. This is the line I have in the script:document.writeln('<td colspan="35" width="1000px" style="background-color: rgba(0,159,227,1);color:white;font-size: larger;break-after: avoid-page">' + value + '</td>');

Comment: Try using the old version: `page-break-after: avoid`. It's possible your browser doesn't support the new property

Comment: also tried to put it in a div and not working neither:
document.writeln('<div style="break-after: avoid-page">');
                    document.writeln('<tr>');
                    document.writeln('<td colspan="35" width="1000px" style="background-color: rgba(0,159,227,1);color:white;font-size: larger">' + value + '</td>');
                    document.writeln('</tr>');
                    document.writeln('</div>');

Comment: I would put your CSS styles in a separate stylesheet and add a class to the `div`, styling the class in the stylesheet